# Link to the product description section

Tags: magento-1.9

I Posted this question on stack overflow, not sure how to move it.

i googled this and couldn't find an answer. I'm trying to link to the product description section in magento, see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Theres no screenshot

Comment: There is. I'm looking at it. Try here http://i.stack.imgur.com/OI1LI.jpg

Comment: Do you mean the javascript method that shows the tab?

Comment: I guess, didnt know it was js. I was hoping I can point to that part. You see how in the short description I say "more information in the DESCRIPTION field below"? I'd like the word DESCRIPTION be a link that points to the sectionof description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to scroll down to the tabs, inspect the element with your browser tools to find out its `id` attribute, then create a link with this id as *fragment*: `<a href="#here_the_id">`

Comment: Will try figuring this out now,  I'm a beginner at websites. Sorry,  I might take a while and thank you

Comment: You're saying that the description section has an id? Or guessing that it should?

Comment: I did not verify it but I'm sure either the tab or the section itself has one

Comment: Id is set by using "dt id", right? I just inspected a page where I have ids set and I was able to see them. However, the product page doesn't have any "dt id". Sorry if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Not dt. Just `id="... "`

Comment: Not sure if I should start a new question. When on the phone it takes you to the description tab but it's not open. You then need to click on it to open it. Is there any way to open it programmatically?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js